# GO reading last line

Tags: string, go, slice

i have a console input

```
b a 
c b 
c a 
c c 
c F
```

and i am reading it like following:

```
wtf:=make([]string,5)
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
for i:=0;i<5;i++{
        line, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        wtf[i]=line
    }
```

But, i am not reading the last line because it has no '\n'
so i've added the following code

```
var kek string
kek=""
for i:=0;i<2;i++{
    line, _:=reader.ReadString(' ')
    kek+=line
    }
```

Now in `wtf` are stored first 4 lines and in `kek` is the last one.
Now i want `kek` to be 4-th element of `wtf`. As i can understand, `wtf` is a slice, so there should be no problem for doing this:

```
wtf[5-1]=kek
```

BUT that's not working, i am getting this output for `wtf`:

```
[
b a
c b
c a
c F
]
```

And if i check `wtf`'s len it would be still 5!

P.S. Total number of lines and symbols to read in it are given, so digits 5 and 2 could be replaced for n and m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
 kek=""
```

That line is unnecessary, kek is already an empty string because an empty string is the nil value for string.

Since you have not shown where your second block of code fits in the first block, I cannot comment on how you got your wrong result.

Anyway, ReadString will read in the last line regardless of whether there is a newline character.  This will work:

```
wtf := make([]string)
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
for {
    line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    wtf = append(wtf, line)
    if err != nil {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [bufio.Scanner](https://godoc.org/bufio#Scanner) instead of bufio.Reader. The bufio.Scanner type was [added in Go 1.1](https://golang.org/doc/go1.1#bufio_scanner) to simplify tasks that are needlessly complex with bufio.Reader.

```
var wtf []string
s := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
for s.Scan() {
    wtf = append(wtf, s.Text())
}
if err := s.Err(); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

The `wtf` elements in the question include the `\n` at the end of each line.  The code in this answer does not.